# android: how to set tabs of tabhost in two lines?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

Now I want to set the tab widget like this style:
[image]

how should I do? All I know the possibility is to modify the Android source code, Any better ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are probably going to need to extend `TabWidget` can't say for sure.

Comment: @herbertD-Hey have you made it o work coz I am having the same problem ...??

Comment: I didn't set the style. You can use ActivityGroup and make your own 'tab widget'. Or, use several buttons and load several Fragment correspondingly.

Comment: @herbertD-I tried that but didnt even reached close to it..!! Can u be more specific..thanks again for reply mate !

Comment: I use Fragment to perform the trick: Please see the Android's Doc. And I use it like this:          FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_APP_DIALOG); 
         if (prev != null) {
          ft.remove(prev);
         }
         // Create and show the dialog.
         DialogFragment newFragment = AppDialogFragment.newInstance(folderName, this, appInfos);
         newFragment.setRetainInstance(false);
         ft.add(mRootLayout.getId(), newFragment, TAG_APP_DIALOG);
         ft.commit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Fragment to perform the trick: Please see the [Android's Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). So you should add for example 4 buttons in what ever layout and show 4 different Fragment by click one of them, below is the sample to show one Fragment:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_APP_DIALOG); 
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    // Create and show the dialog fragment.
    DialogFragment newFragment = AppDialogFragment.newInstance(folderName, this, appInfos);
    newFragment.setRetainInstance(false);
    ft.add(mRootLayout.getId(), newFragment, TAG_APP_DIALOG);
    ft.commit();
```